# parse.com action-loc-key push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to find an answer to this all over but I just can't. I know that to change the title of the button on the push notifications on iOS 8 from "View" to something else, I have to specify it in `action-loc-key`, but how would I do this specifically with Parse.com? Would I create a `NSDictionary` for `alert` and make it a key under there and then add that `NSDictionary` to the JSON payload for the push data or would I add it directly to the push data? Can someone give me an example? T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly set the `aps` dictionary of the `data` field of the Parse push payload and set the action-loc-keys exactly as described by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21).

```
var payload = 
  "data":{  
    "aps":{  
       "alert":{  
          "loc-key":"msg",
          "loc-args":["John"],
          "action-loc-key":"rsp"
       },
    }
  };
// set at least the 'where' key of the payload
Parse.Push.send(payload);
```